# difference between aggregate ($match) and find, in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

What is the difference between the `$match` operator used inside the aggregate function and the regular `find` in Mongodb?

Why doesn't the `find` function allow renaming the field names like the aggregate function? 
e.g. In aggregate we can pass the following string:

```
{ "$project" : { "OrderNumber" : "$PurchaseOrder.OrderNumber" , "ShipDate" : "$PurchaseOrder.ShipDate"}}
```

Whereas, find does not allow this.

Why does not the aggregate output return as a DBCursor or a List? and also why can't we get a count of the documents that are returned?

Thank you.

Comment: [MongoDB 2.6 aggregation operations will return a cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-operations-now-return-cursors).

Answer (score 33):

> Why does not the aggregate output return as a DBCursor or a List?

The aggregation framework was created to solve easy problems that otherwise would require map-reduce.

This framework is commonly used to compute data that requires the full db as input and few document as output.

> What is the difference between the $match operator used inside the aggregate function and the regular find in Mongodb?

One of differences, like you stated, is the return type. Find operations output return as a *DBCursor*.

Other differences:

- Aggregation result must be [under 16MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/#result). If you are using [shards](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/), the full data [must be collected in a single point](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/#memory-for-cumulative-operators) after the first [*$group*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#stage._S_group) or [*$sort*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/#stage._S_sort).
- *$match* only purpose is to improve aggregation's power, but it has some other uses, like improve the aggregation performance.

> and also why can't we get a count of the documents that are returned?

You can. Just count the number of elements in the resulting array or add the following command to the end of the pipe:

```js
{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}
```

> Why doesn't the find function allow renaming the field names like the aggregate function?

MongoDB is young and features are still coming. Maybe in a future version we'll be able to do that. Renaming fields is more critical in *aggregation* than in *find*.

## EDIT (2014/02/26):

[MongoDB 2.6 aggregation operations will return a cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-operations-now-return-cursors).

## EDIT (2014/04/09):

[MongoDB 2.6 was released with the predicted aggregation changes](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-enhancements).

Comment: Update: In mongo 3.4 you can count in aggregate by `{$count:"number_of_elements"}`

Answer (score 0):

I investigated a few things about the aggregation and find call: 
I did this with a descending sort in a table of 160k documents and limited my output to a few documents.

1. The Aggregation command is slower than the find command.
2. If you access to the data like `ToList()` the aggregation command is faster than the find.
3. if you watch at the total times (point 1 + 2) the commands seem to be equal

Maybe the aggregation automatically calls the `ToList()` and does not have to call it again. If you dont call `ToList()` afterwards the `find()` call will be much faster.

*7 [ms] vs 50 [ms] (5 documents)*